# Kotlin: Is this a good way to avoid memory leaks?

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton, android-context, dagger-hilt

I was always facing this memory leak warning without paying much attention to it, but now I'm looking into how to deal with it and, as I know I shouldn't use WeakReference and that sort of "tricks" to avoid it, come to what I think could be a possible and simple solution.

My idea is as follows:

I have a singleton class (object) which holds all my app configuration, where I initialize a context from the Application class like this:

```
object AppSettings {

    lateinit var context: Context

    fun init(appContext: Context){
        this.context = appContext
    }
    
    /* OTHER STUFF */
}

typealias aw = AppSettings

@HiltAndroidApp
class AWApplication : MultiDexApplication() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        AppSettings.init(this)

    }
    
    /* OTHER STUFF */
}
```

I initialize that context not only in ApplicationClass, but in every activity OnCreate (which inherits from BaseActivity):

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
open class BaseActivity {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        AppSettings.init(this)
    }
}
```

And finally, I can access context wherever it is needed as follows:

```
object RandomObject {
    fun DoWhatever() {
        PlayAFreddieMercurySong(aw.context,)
    }
}
```

Well, this is my possible solution and I would like to know Android gurus from SO opinion about it.

Maybe I'm leaking memory in my App Settings -where I had initially store context-, but Android Studio is not complaining about it, so I am not sure.

In the end, I'm trying to avoid passing context as a method parameter in every place it is needed for code simplicity.

Comment: "Maybe I'm leaking memory in my AppSettings -where I initially store context" - incorrect, initial context set in Application will live as long as the app process. Also seeing as this will always be mutated in each activity it will only be a short term leak until the previous Activity's context variable  is mutated to the current Activity.. however not sure how you then pass this context around in your functions.. these could easily leak if any hold a reference. I'd not advocate this is a very good way to reference a context for convenience purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Mark. According to your response, what do you think could be a proper way to have a context available in all my helper/utility classes? I have to add that my helper classes are objects (because accessing methods in a static way is convenient for me), and context cannot be injected into objects. In short, I'm looking for the best -or at least a proper- way to have a context available in all my helper classes in the methods where is needed, avoiding to pass it as a method parameter if possible.

Comment: I don't discard the option to pass context as a parameter to the functions where it is needed, but I'm trying to avoid this option for code simplicity, and remember that one of the statements of clean code is "Take the methods parameters count to a minimum. A max. of 3 is recommended".

Comment: @DiegoPerez write the code you need, don't compromise it by putting unnecessary restrictions on things like how many dependencies it has. Being mindful of things like large parameter counts is fine (e.g. maybe you need some kind of config/state object to bundle a lot of data as one parameter) but treat it as a guideline, not a rule. Passing a `Context` to other classes and functions is incredibly common and a standard way of doing things in Android - there's a good chance that's why you need access to one in the first place!

Comment: "one of the statements of clean code is Take the methods parameters count to a minimum" - sorry but thats is a very weak argument to advocate calling global state in helper functions, you can always use tuples or builder pattern to supply function params as one object, with many internal variables? Does clean code also state calling global state anywhere in your code, dependencies should point inwards. You seem set on defending the position of using singletons and imperative programming over dependency injection and OOP - so just stick with what you are doing how you want.

Comment: Thanks again @Mark, I'm not stuck (or set) to anything, if I posted an answer in SO is because I'm trying to use best practices. I always defend to take my code to its best, and although I may be wrong in some of my assumptions, my intention is clear. I appreciate every response here, because it is time and effort of the guy who is replying. Maybe I'm completely wrong trying to avoid passing context as a parameter, in that case you give me your arguments against that and of course I'll consider them. After some responses I come to two options, using extension methods or parameter context :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"other stuff"** are common between all activities and they need just **ApplicationContext**, then why you don't use application context in AppSettings. and thats it. BTW your solution will not leak, if and only if you call your AppSettings.init(this) in all activities.
and you don't guarantee that .

> **in other words "the code doesn't leak now but may be in the future" - vulnerable**

---

> if you have functions thats related to activities, fragments or any
> class you want, you can use extension functions for that

you should create a kotlin file with name for ex ActivityExt. and write all of your cases that you need for activities . if you need functions for fragments you should also create another kotlin file with name FragmentExt..etc

Comment: Thanks 4 your reply @Mohmmaed-Amleh. Mostly -as u say- I need ApplicationContext, but there are specific cases where I need an ActivityContext, 4 ex, in my AppearanceHelper there is a SetStatusBarColor (accessible by all activities) that needs an ActivityContext to access window and set StatusBar Color (this is just an example): activity.window.statusBarColor = Color.parseColor(app.statusBarColor), so, this is the reason why I set ActivityContext in every activity onCreate, to be sure I'll have it when needed, so, what do you think could be the best way to accomplish that?

Comment: Maybe I should create a generic ViewModel accessible by all activities and put all methods that require an ActivityContext there? Do you think that could be a better solution than the one I'm describing @Mohmmaed-Amleh? I'm not sure all methods that require an ActivityContext are view related (to put them into a generic ViewModel), but I'm just asking as another possible solution.

Comment: BTW @Mohmmaed-Amleh, I haven't injected ApplicationContext into my AppSettings because it's an object, not a class, and Hilt -as you already know- cannot inject in objects. Why an object? Because for me accessing all app configuration variables in a static way is very convenient.

Comment: for injecting in object yeah maybe we cant inject in object  class you are right ... but my idea reach you .. i quote "4 ex, in my AppearanceHelper there is a SetStatusBarColor (accessible by all activities) that needs an ActivityContext" these things should be "extension functions"  . you should create a kotlin file with name for ex ActivityExt .
and write all of your cases that you need for activities .
if you need functions for fragments u should also create another kotlin file with name FragmentExt

Comment: Thanks again @Mohmmaed-Amleh. I love extension functions, so if you write this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @DiegoPerez i update the answer

Comment: Thank you very much @@Mohmmaed-Amleh, answer accepted. Would you be so kind to help me with this other similar post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73510869/kotlin-hilt-class-cannot-be-provided-without-an-provides-annotated-method-wh