# Dagger hilt injected object is null in custom view

Tags: android, kotlin, code-injection, dagger, dagger-hilt

I am trying to inject a `class` (`ExampleClass`) in a `custom view` (`CustomView`), it extends from a `class` called `BaseWidget` which extends from `LinearLayout`.

I have this class, which I want to inject to my custom view.

```
class ExampleClass @Inject constructor(val api: Api) {...}
```

The Api is provided in a `@Module` (because it's `Retrofit`).

`CustomView` is declared in the `XML` layout of a `Fragment` (`ExampleFragment`), which is contained in an `Activity` `ExampleActivity`

Here comes the code:

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.example.ui.widget.CustomView
    android:id="@+id/customview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

CustomView (in java):

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
public class CustomView extends BaseWidget {

@Inject
ExampleClass exampleClassInjected;

...
}
```

`Fragment` and `activity` are also annotated with `@AndroidEntryPoint`.

The thing is that the value of `exampleClassInjected` is always `null` in `CustomView`, but if I move that to the `fragment` or the `activity`, it has a value.

I don't understand why is null in the custom view but not in `fragment` or `activity`, what I'm missing?

EDIT:

I was trying to use the injected class in the CustomView constructor, and it's null in that moment, but if I wait until Fragment's onViewCreated() that injected class in customView is not null anymore, so I don't really understand, dagger is working properly, but it seems it's waiting until fragment is full created to inject the custom view

Comment: How did you annotated the scope for ExampleClass in di module?  And, please, check if all the override methods for CustomView are using super.

Comment: @polis Example class is not annotated in module because it's mine and I own it, the only one that is annotated there (as singletonComponent) is Api. Yes, it has all the super methods, with context and so on

Answer (score 0):

no need for any annotation for custom classes ,if you use `constructer inject` . >> just remove @AndroidEntryPoint
..........
if you want `field injection`  read my answer for this question.[how filed injection work with dagger-hilt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73510869/kotlin-hilt-class-cannot-be-provided-without-an-provides-annotated-method-wh/73534922#73534922)

Comment: In my case CustomView extends from LinearLayout, so a View is accepted by hilt, that's the reason I put @AndroidEntryPoint

Comment: add @ WithFragmentBindings along with your @ AndroidEntryPoint

Comment: Also tried without success. I'm moving to KOIN